# CustomObjectTranslation fields are empty via Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, customobjecttranslation

I want to access the translations of the values of a picklist.
I use the following code:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

list<String> tList = new list<String>();
tList.add('myp__Employee__c-en_US');
MetadataService.ReadCustomObjectTranslationResult tr = (MetadataService.ReadCustomObjectTranslationResult)service.readMetadata('CustomObjectTranslation', tList);
```

However, when I debug the result **tr.records[0].fields** is null.
tr.records[0] does give a record with fullname=myp__Employee__c-en_US but if I use a nonexisting sObject name it also gives a record back with the wrong fullName.

It looks like I'm doing something wrong but I can't find out what. Who can help?

P.S. I succesfully can read data like picklists from an sObject, external site settings, etc.. via the Metadata API